# R code to show table of observations under line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need a table with the number of observations under a line graph as in this example:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R01E.png)

Any help would be appreciated..

This is what I tried so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyr)

# Example data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  time = 1:10,
  group1_value = cumsum(rnorm(10)),
  group2_value = cumsum(rnorm(10)),
  group1_count = sample(20:50, 10, replace = TRUE),
  group2_count = sample(20:50, 10, replace = TRUE)
)

# Reshape data for easier plotting
df_long <- pivot_longer(df, cols = c(group1_value, group2_value),
                        names_to = "group", values_to = "value")

# Create the plot
plot <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x = time, y = value, color = group)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Group 1 and Group 2") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 1, 0), "lines"))  # Adjust bottom margin to leave space for the table

# Create a data frame for the table
table_data <- data.frame(
  Time = df$time,
  Group1 = df$group1_count,
  Group2 = df$group2_count
)

# Create the table
table_grob <- tableGrob(table_data)

# Adjust table appearance
table_grob$widths <- unit(rep(1, ncol(table_data)), "null")
table_grob$heights <- unit(rep(1, nrow(table_data) + 1), "null")
table_grob$vp <- NULL

# Arrange plot and table
grid.arrange(
  plot, table_grob,
  ncol = 1,
  heights = c(3, 1)  # Adjust the relative heights of the plot and table
)
```

Comment: thanks for adding the data in, though for future reference please dont delete and repost a question that hasn't been answered, but instead edit the original question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach which uses `ggplot2` to create the table and uses `patchwork` to glue the plot and the table together.

Note: I slightly simplified the reshaping so that we get a value and a count column in one go.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(patchwork)

df_long <- pivot_longer(df,
  cols = starts_with("group"),
  names_to = c("group", ".value"),
  names_sep = "_"
)

plot <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x = time, y = value, color = group)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Group 1 and Group 2")

table <- ggplot(df_long) +
  geom_text(aes(
    x = time, y = group, label = count
  ), size = .8 * 11 / .pt) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = scales::breaks_width(1),
    position = "top"
  ) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(color = "black"),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(y = NULL, x = NULL, title = "My table title")

plot / table +
  plot_layout(axes = "collect", heights = c(3, 1))
```

[image]